# How to check which services are using too much memory

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, performance, services

I have a Windows 10 laptop that constantly has high memory usage, even on idle. I did a selective startup with Microsoft and Intel services only, but the memory usage was only marginally lower than previously and still approaching 70%.

When I go to task manager to check the memory usage of the “Processes”, every one of them is low and they don’t add up too much, certainly not 70% as it is shown, and it just seems that something hidden is using a lot of memory that’s not on the list.

Are Services excluded from “Processes”? How can I check which services are using high memory?

Comment: Do you have an actual problem you suspect is due to low available memory? Unused memory is wasted memory, and so modern OSes will fill the memory in order to provide maximum speed benefit to the system and software running on it. Simply seeing high memory usage is not itself a problem.

Comment: How much memory do you have? Windows 64-bit will typically use 4GB at idle and then more as needed.

Comment: 8 GB ram, the processes don’t even add up to 4GB

Comment: @music2myear yeah it constantly has fans on while just running one thing in the foreground, then i check task manager and CPU and graphics card usage are both low, i worry about the longevity of my laptop

Comment: 70 % is 5 to 6 GB.  Modern browsers with many tabs use a lot of memory.  That is one possible reason

Comment: @John okay that could be the reason. But is there a way to see how much memory a service is using tho? Just in case

Comment: Memory use and CPU use are different.  Run Admin Tools, Resource Monitor for 15 minutes and see what is using CPU.

Comment: @John CPU usage is low

Comment: Memory usage will NOT shorten the life of a laptop.  So long as temp is OK you are fine.  My oldest laptop is 10 years old

Comment: Constant fans? Are the fans running high rpm, or just spinning a little bit? Do they ramp up to higher speed (more noise) when you generate a load on the system? You still haven't indicated any sort of real problem. Also, the question should not be in your comments. As these comments remind or inform you, edit your question to make it more clear.